# Fortran Bus Error When Modifying Parameter

Tags: parameters, fortran, bus-error

Whenever I assign a new value to a parameter, I get a bus error. I don't see how I'm pointing to non-existant memory. I should have access to this address, as it is declared in the parameter list, unless Fortran does not allow parameters to be modified without some special declaration. The rest of my code works without error. I've isolated it to simply this assignment.

I'm running gfortran (not sure which version, off-hand) from the terminal in OS X.

```
SUBROUTINE p_list (c_number, c_matrix)
    INTEGER     c_number
    INTEGER     c_matrix(8000,20)
!   ... 
    c_number = 1000
!   ...
END SUBROUTINE p_list
```

Comment: How are you calling this? I don't know modern FORTRANs, but I know that with earlier versions of FORTRAN, you could crash a program like that by passing in a constant (e.g., by calling `p_list(0, my_matrix)`). That's because FORTRAN implicitly passed everything by reference, including constants (!)

Comment: Actually, great catch. The call from main was a test line of code using a constant. Replacing it with a declared INTEGER in the call, seemed to do the trick! Promote this comment to an answer, and I'll select it as the winner. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to "win" a FORTRAN question, but OK ;-)

Comment: @Old McStopher: I suggest you declare INTENTs on arguments to subroutines; you'll get a lot more help from the compiler.  From your questions so far you seem to be learning an antiquated version of Fortran, more recent versions provide the necessary features to write much safer programs.

Comment: Are INTENTs supported in the F77 standard? 'Tis antiquated, indeed, but such is the requirement for this project, unfortunately. Thanks for taking an interest in my line of questions. [I just posted another, if you're interested... ;)]

Comment: @Old McStopher - Should we presume you don't have an f90 compilant compiler?

Comment: I'm actually using what I trust is a fairly-recent GNU version of gfortran, so I think it's good through F95.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you calling this? I don't know modern FORTRANs, but I know that with earlier versions of FORTRAN, you could crash a program like that by passing in a constant (e.g., by calling p_list(0, my_matrix)). That's because FORTRAN implicitly passed everything by reference, including constants (!)